# How to make a JButton that when pressed it does a new action

Tags: java, swing, random, jbutton

I wanted to create a rock/paper/scissors game and add the function to implement a button which gives the user the option to replay the game without having to re-run the program, but when I press the "Do it again" button the random choice of the computer is always the same, how to do it that it picks a new random string from the array.

```
JButton button1 = new JButton("The choice");
JButton button2 = new JButton("Do it again");
JTextField tekst1 = new JTextField(20);
Container c = getContentPane();
c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
c.add(tekst1);
c.add(button1);
c.add(button2);

button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (!hasBeenClicked) {
            button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                String[] arr={"rock", "paper", "scissors"};
                Random r=new Random();
                int randomNumber=r.nextInt(arr.length);

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    tekst1.setText(arr[randomNumber]);
                }
            });
        } else {
            tekst1.setText("");
        }
        hasBeenClicked = ! hasBeenClicked;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you generate a random number once outside the on-click event. Move it to the method a few lines below:

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    String[] arr={"rock", "paper", "scissors"};
    Random r=new Random();

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        int randomNumber=r.nextInt(arr.length);
        tekst1.setText(arr[randomNumber]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it

Answer (score 1):

move `int randomNumber=r.nextInt(arr.length);` into actionPerformed